# PostgreSQL - Escape single quote in an column alias

Tags: postgresql, column-alias

How to escape single quote in an column alias in PostgreSQL?

I tried several syntaxes without success:

```
SELECT 'Test 1' AS 'O''Connell';

SELECT 'Test 2' AS 'O\'Connell';

SELECT 'Test 3' AS "O''Connell";
```

PgAdmin screenshot

[image: pgadmin_screenshot]

Comment: Identifiers are double quoted so: `SELECT "Test 3" AS "O''Connell" FROM ...;` See [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver "test 3" would be a column, not a text, and the column name would contain 2 single quotes...

Comment: @JGH, if you paid attention to the question you would see that GeoGyro is asking about a column alias and not a string alias and my suggestion is correct for that application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quote for the identifier, and one single quote inside:

```sql
SELECT 'Test 3' AS "O'Connell";

 O'Connell
-----------
 Test 3
```

Comment: Ok. And when I use a field in my query like `SELECT field AS "O'Connell" FROM table;` ?

Comment: @GeoGyro yes, like for any other alias :)

Comment: Except the answer will fail if `'Test 3'` is a column in a table. Identifiers need to be double quoted. Please revise your answer to be correct.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver as in the question, `'test 3'` is a string, a constant if you want, that is selected as a column. This column should have an alias, and my answer address this point just fine.

Comment: Ok thanks. PgAdmin display confused me with the red syntax (see my post for screenshot).

Comment: @GeoGyro you can trick the (not too bright) color parser by adding a single quote in comments after the alias `select myfield as "o'connor" /*'*/, myOtherField from...`